# Dependent submit button in angular to fetch JSON file and display

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm working on an AngularJS project, also pretty new to this and have managed to create a dependent drop-down menu.

Example:
Parent Drop-down- Cars
                - Bikes

Child Drop-down- BMW, Audi
               - Yamaha, Honda

So from the above example, if I choose Cars in the first drop-down it will display BMW and Audi in the second drop-down. Same for bikes.

Now if the user chooses BMW and clicks the submit button I want it to redirect to a URL which contains a JSON file and display the result in the form of a table.

If the user chooses Yamaha similarly it should redirect to another JSON URL and display the result in a table.

How can this be achieved in AngularJS, with a single "Submit" button?

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: though it quite simple. But have you tried anything yourself. Please post relevant code. And create a minimal demo

Comment: I'm using the same code as available here: http://embed.plnkr.co/cnPM0J/preview any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @FranklinFrancis your example is too complex, consider this simple case: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BKN5RcEq7dYkFwkg4M2U?p=preview), which you can adjust for your example (with dropdowns, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your vehicle dropdown should have unique ID such as cars for 1, bikes for 2 here 1 and 2 are unique ID for this category of vehicles.

Now on submit call a function which will take you to another page now, send this uniqueID of vehicles into statparams and on that page and on page OnInit make a http call and bind the models to that dropdown.